# EMGU CV MCvBox2D.GetVertices gives different order of corners

Tags: c#, emgucv, rectangles

I'm using EMGU CV for my project and I'm facing a weird problem.
I use cannyedges to find some squares in a photo.
This is working correctly. After that i want to take a pixel inside each square and use that to draw the border.

The problem I'm facing is that i need the vertices of each corner in order to generate a random pixel.
To do this I use the code:

```
PointF[] corners = rectangle.GetVertices();
float x = Math.Max(corners[1].X, corners[0].X);
float y = Math.Max(corners[1].Y, corners[2].Y);
float width = Math.Min(corners[2].X, corners[3].X) - x;
float height = Math.Min(corners[0].Y, corners[3].Y) - y;
```

The problem with this code is that rectangle.GetVertices(); gives a different order of corners each time.
The first rectangle returns bottomleft as corner 0, top left as corner 1 etc.
How ever the second rectangle returns bottomright as corner 0, bottomleft as corner 1  etc.

I'm wondering if anyone else is having this problem and if anyone knows how to fix this?
If you need more info to answer this problem please tell me.

Comment: I am having this same problem. The vertices comes on different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PointF[] corners = rectangle.GetVertices();

// Maybe this
corners = corners.OrderBy(s => s.X).ThenBy(s => s.Y).ToArray();

float x = Math.Max(corners[1].X, corners[0].X);
float y = Math.Max(corners[1].Y, corners[2].Y);
float width = Math.Min(corners[2].X, corners[3].X) - x;
float height = Math.Min(corners[0].Y, corners[3].Y) - y;
```